# how we can design .net core api controller to accept an array value of strings

Tags: api, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-2.1

I would like to know how we can design .net core api controller to accept an array value like given below

```
http://localhost:32656/api/Values?str[]="abc"&str[]="xyz"
```

I did some research online and the only two options, I was able to find is either I need to pass indexes inside the array
    eg:- http://localhost:32656/api/Values?str[0]="abc"&str[1]="xyz"  (Pass indexes inside the array)

or I need to pass the array as repeated query strings.
    eg:- http://localhost:32656/api/Values?str="abc"&str="xyz"  (Pass it as repeated query strings)

But I would like to see the other possible options to send an array to .net core 2.1 api controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [`FromQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2) attribute here, specifying the [`Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute.name?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_FromQueryAttribute_Name) property as `str[]`:

```cs
public IActionResult Values([FromQuery(Name = "str[]")] List<string> strValues)
{
    ...
}
```

If you also want to strip out the `"`s for each value, you can use a `Select`. Here's a an example:

```cs
public IActionResult Values([FromQuery(Name = "str[]")] List<string> strValues)
{
    var strValuesWithoutQuotes = strValues.Select(x => x.Trim('"'));

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we do it:

```
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task Get(List<string> stringValues)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then call the endpoint with `http://localhost/api/v1/test?stringValues=string1&stringValues=string2`

stringValues should have the list of values in the query string

Comment: Thanks Cale for the quick reply. This is how I am currently doing. But I need to change the api call in to this format.  http://localhost:32656/api/Values?str[]="abc"&str[]="xyz" . I need to add square brackets in to the URL. Thanks.

Comment: are you unable to update the calling system? I haven't seen that url syntax before, and I am not sure .net core will support it

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to change the calling system. Thanks for your support. Have a great day.